# Loopback - can't show error from controller

Tags: loopback

I'm new to loopback and I'm trying to return an error from a rest api controller created by cli with
"lb4 controller"
I don't know why Loopback always insert the data in db: what am I doing wrong???

Here is the code

```
 @post('/tavolos', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Tavolo model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: getModelSchemaRef(Tavolo)}},
      },
    },
  })
  async createTavolo(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Tavolo, {
            title: 'NewTavolo',
            exclude: ['id'],
          }),
        },
      },
    })
    tavolo: Omit<Tavolo, 'id'>,
  ): Promise<Tavolo> {
    if (!Number.isInteger(Tavolo.max) || Tavolo.max > 10) {
      throw new HttpErrors.BadRequest( `error text`, );
    }

    return this.tavoloRepository.create(tavolo);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself: i just recreated the project (all models, controllers, etc...) and now it works... don't know where the error is.